# ACF Lighbox Issue

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

My site imports data from an external site via a JSON file. However it is required that images display on my site externally. So, using ACF, i make the image urls import into a repeater field then create a gallery with them like so:

```
<?php while(the_repeater_field('gallery')): ?>

<ul><li>                
<a class="fancybox" href="<?php the_sub_field('image'); ?>">
    <img src="<?php echo get_sub_field('image'); ?>"/> 
</a></li></ul>
```

I am trying to get the images work with Fancybox but when i click on the images all i ever get is the popup box to save the image to my computer, no lightbox.

Any advice?

Comment: i think you should try use javascript.

Comment: Have you included Fancybox js and CSS files properly?
Also, I think your ul tag should go above the while loop.